# Adding data to data attribute that contains array (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html code that has a data attribute named data-keys which is an array. I want to add values to this array by javascript. What function can I use in order to do this?

```
<input type="text" data-keys="[]">
```

Comment: What I understand it that HTML attributes always have strings as their values. You can definitely store an array converted into string though as a value in data-* attribute.

Answer (score 0):

While this is semi-possible for values that are serializable (objects, arrays, and primitives)...

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
// retrieve array
const keysArr = JSON.parse(input.dataset.keys);

keysArr.push('foo');

// set array to dataset again
input.dataset.keys = JSON.stringify(keysArr);

// retrieve array to show that it's changed
console.log(input.dataset.keys);
```

```html
<input type="text" data-keys="[]">
```

It's very, very strange. A much better approach would be to store the values in JavaScript instead. If you need to associate each input to an array, consider using a Map instead.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const keysByInputs = new Map([
  [input, []]
]);

// retrieve array
const keysArr = keysByInputs.get(input);
keysArr.push('foo');

// retrieve array to show that it's changed
console.log(keysByInputs.get(input));
```

```html
<input type="text" data-keys="[]">
```

Answer (score -1):

Since attribute values are strings, you will have to convert from string to JSON and vice versa. These functions will do just that:

- [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Additionally, you'll want to use functions to get a hold of the element, as well as get and set its attribute(s). May I suggest these:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)
- [`element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Alternatively to the more general purpose `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()`, you could also use [`element.dataset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) in your particular case.